# Correct way to use LinkProperty with Go and AMQP 1.0

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

There is a RabbitMQ server with an enabled AMQP 1.0 plugin. The queue with the name **receiver** is durable and has an 'x-message-ttl' parameter value of 6000.

I'm using the [github.com/Azure/go-amqp](https://github.com/Azure/go-amqp) library. When I create a `session.NewSender` in such a way:

```golang
sender, err := session.NewSender(
            amqp.LinkProperty("x-message-ttl", "6000"),
            amqp.LinkTargetAddress("receiver"),
            amqp.LinkTargetDurability(amqp.DurabilityConfiguration),
        )
```

the server returns an error:

> creating sender link: session ended by server: *Error{Condition: amqp:precondition-failed, Description: PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'receiver' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '6000' of type 'long', Info: map[]}

What is the correct way to pass the 'x-message-ttl' parameter?

Comment: Did you try message-ttl parameter (without "x-")?

Comment: Unfortunately, without "x-" the result is the same.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Any solution to it?